# Limit of a sequence with nth root of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Question: find the limit of a sequence $\{a_n\}$ where:

$a_n = \sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=1}^n  (2 - \frac{1}{k})^k}$.

It's easy to prove that $a_n$ is bounded by $2$ from above:

$\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=1}^n  (2 - \frac{1}{k})^k} \leqslant \sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=1}^n  (2 - \frac{1}{k})^n} \to 2$.

How do I got about bounding it from below?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly, $$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(2-\frac1k\right)^k\ge \left(2-\frac1n\right)^n$$ So $$\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=1}^n \left(2-\frac1k\right)^k}\ge \sqrt[n]{\left(2-\frac1n\right)^n}=2-\frac1n\to2$$